# How to write functions to generate number related to checkbox value?

Tags: javascript, html

I selected  unwanted numbers in checkbox.
I want to generate 1-3 digits numbers that are not included the checkbox value.
How can I perform function?

Comment: Please show code that you've tried to write already

Comment: You can use random function to create numbers(1-3 digits) inside a loop, and store only numbers different from the checkbox value.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code

Comment: Are you saying you have 10 checkboxes, one for each of the digits 0 through 9? Or...? Please [edit] your question to explain in more detail and show the code you already have.